# Android - NullPointer in signed application does not occurs when app is installed from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, nullpointerexception, android-support-library

I'm developing an Android App using:

```
support v4
support v7 appcompat
gridlayout v7
```

support libriaries.

When I install this app in my android phone using eclipse, everything works.
When I try to export/sign this app and when I install created .apk file, I have the following exception filling a listView:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  
at  my.app.ar.getView(Unknown
at  android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
at  android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
at  android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
at  android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
at  android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1646)
at  android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7277)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7277)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7277)
at  android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7277)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7277)
at  android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7277)
at  android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7277)
at  android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1203)
at  android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1957)
at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
```

But this problem never occurs if the app is installed from eclipse.

The following code is where I'm filling a ListView and when (I think) is raised the exception:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    }

    final SheetVO userSheet = this.sheets.get(position);
    final ProductVO product = userSheet.getProduct();

    TextView textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userScanRowView);
    textViewItem.setText(product.getName());
    textViewItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SheetActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("idSheet", userSheet.getId());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Is this an export/signing process error?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Given the failure occurs between debug and exported, signed builds, my gut instinct would be to suspect your proguard configuration.  But if that were teh cause it's not fully clear why you are getting a null pointer exception rather than a class not found exception, so that may not be it.  The code of my.app.ar.getView would be useful for you to post.  Or perhaps proguard is leaving the class, but eliminating this method since simply static analysis suggests it is not called by any java code?

Comment: Thanks Tushar and Chris. I posted the invoked code.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, had the right idea! Disabling proguard, everythink works. Now I'm trying to properly configure proguard.

I still have the error using common configuration:
`code`
    -dontwarn android.support.**
    -libraryjars libs
    -keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
    -keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Could be differences between debug/release builds. You might have forgotten to initialize a variable which in the debug build is filled in for you.

Create a release build (unsigned) and see if that crashes too. Since this type of issue is difficult to debug, one approach is to sprinkle log statements throughout the suspect function. Look at the output to narrow down exactly which function call crashes.

Also validate that the parameters passed to getView are correct.

Comment: Thanks @pmont, but the problem is in the proguard configuration.
Disabling it, I temporary solved the problem.
I'm looking for the right configuration, to keep proguard running properly